# Opening a different activities with different NFC tags

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc

I'm currently programming a quiz with `NFC` tags. 
To play the quiz, you walk from station to station. There is one `NFC` tag at each station. I want to hold my mobile phone to a `NFC` tag and then the correct question for the current station will appear.
My tags currently contain different `strings`. 
Unfortunately I can't find anything that helps me. Do you have an idea?